# How to store and recursively read ExtJS component like this?

Tags: json, extjs, recursion

The layout below is what I want to implement in a webpage. I'd like to store it as a JSON-like file, my question is :

1. How should I store it, especially, those lines of function stuff?Strictly obeying JSON style, or anything else?
2. After stored successfully, how to set up my model?
3. How can I read it from Ext.data.store recursively, or by loop?

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
{
            'xtype': 'tabpanel',
            'activeTab': 0,
            'width': 600,
            'height': 250,
            'plain': true,
            'defaults' :{
                'autoScroll': true,
                'bodyPadding': 10
            },
            'items': [{
                    'title': 'Normal Tab',
                    'html': "My content was added during construction."
                },{
                    'title': 'Ajax Tab 1',
                    'loader': {
                        'url': 'ajax1.htm',
                        'contentType': 'html',
                        'loadMask': true
                    },
                    'listeners': {
                        'activate': function(tab) {
                            tab.loader.load();
                        }
                    }
                },{
                    'title': 'Ajax Tab 2',
                    'loader': {
                        'url': 'ajax2.htm',
                        'contentType': 'html',
                        'autoLoad': true,
                        'params': 'foo=123&bar=abc'
                    }
                },{
                    'title': 'Event Tab',
                    'listeners': {
                        'activate': function(tab){
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                alert(tab.title + ' was activated.');
                            }, 1);
                        }
                    },
                    'html': "I am tab 4's content. I also have an event listener attached."
                },{
                    'title': 'Disabled Tab',
                    'disabled': true,
                    'html': "Can't see me cause I'm disabled"
                }
            ]

      }
```

Comment: Please don't do it why would you want to do that ? It was bad idea for html it is a worst idea for extjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to store the functions as strings and parse them later, the same way Sencha Architect does.

This is a snippet created with Sencha Architect

```
"implHandler": [
    "setTimeout(function(){",
    "   alert(tab.title + ' was activated'); ",
    "},1);"
]
```

So you would have to store your code like this

```
{
    "xtype": "tabpanel",
    "activeTab": 0,
    "width": 600,
    "height": 250,
    "plain": true,
    "defaults" : {
        "autoScroll": true,
        "bodyPadding": 10
    },
    "items": [{
            "title": "Normal Tab",
            "html": "My content was added during construction."
        },{
            "title": "Ajax Tab 1",
            "loader": {
                "url": "ajax1.htm",
                "contentType": "html",
                "loadMask": true
            },
            "listeners": {
                "activate": "function(tab) {tab.loader.load();}"
            }
        },{
            "title": "Ajax Tab 2",
            "loader": {
                "url": "ajax2.htm",
                "contentType": "html",
                "autoLoad": true,
                "params": "foo=123&bar=abc"
            }
        },{
            "title": "Event Tab",
            "listeners": {
                "activate": "function(tab){setTimeout(function() {alert(tab.title + ' was activated.');}, 1);"
            }
        },{
            "html" : "I am tab 4's content. I also have an event listener attached."
        },{
            "title": "Disabled Tab",
            "disabled": true,
            "html": "Can't see me cause I'm disabled"
        }
    ]

}
```

After this you would need to create a model with each field and create a parser to render this as component later.

I don't know what you are trying to do, but it seems like a lot of work.

Comment: Thanks, Guilherme Lopes! The reason why I want to do it like this is that I've modified WebDesktop example and passed the codes above as a parameter so that I'm able to dynamically change the layout framework of my website as needed. It seems like those templates stuff in PHP. I sill have some questions:1. Whether am I able to generically create a parser for it or not? Should I have to parse them separately? This is definitely not what I want.

Comment: 2. Json style as you implemented can't be used as parameter directly, are there basic rules that I'm able to take in my parser in order to reduce the complexity? Say, if the root is xtype=tab-panel, my parser can go like this, and xtype = panel, my parser goes like that.

Comment: The example themes and its implementation style are fairly complicated, it seems that it is not Ajax, when the theme changed by selecting the combobox, there's a POST and GET action fired, it'll take a while to get the theme changed, it is unacceptable for me.

Comment: I've never really tried to implement a system like this so I really couldn't say. But I think you should try your best and when you run into some issues, post another question here.

Comment: Hi, Guilherme Lopes, would you please take a look at my new thread about recursion thing. Thanks.

Comment: Tao, if this thread here is over and you have a new question. Please, mark this as answered.

Comment: [My new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088807/where-is-the-bug-in-my-recursive-json-parser). Thank you, please take a look at here.