# Where is the bug in my recursive JSON parser?

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, recursion, extjs4

I'd like to create a recursive function to parse json-like data as below. When key is xtype, a new class will be created. In particular, when xtype = gridpanel/treepanel, all the properties have to be its constructor argument, otherwise, properties will be added after class has been created.
My recursive function as below, I got an error 'too much recursion' at line 21 in ext-all.js.

Please take a look, how am I able to solve this problem?

codes in main program:

```
    me.recursiveParser(null, data.json);
    Ext.apply(me.root, me.parent);
    me.desktopCfg = me.root;
```

recursiveParser function:

```
    recursiveParser: function(nodeName, jsonData) {
             var properties = {};
             var isSpecial = false;
             var isLeaf = true;
             var parent, child, special;

              //Base factor
                    for (var key in jsonData) {
                      var value = jsonData[key];
                      //To collect all the properties that is only initialized with '@'.
                      if (key.toString().indexOf("@") === 0) {
                                key = key.replace("@", "");
                                if(typeof(value) === "string"){
                                     properties[key] = "'"+value+"'";
                                }else{
                                      //Later, should have to deal with the empty value or array with no keys and only elements.
                                      properties[key] = value;
                                }
                                if(key === "xtype"){
                                     //To initialize the root
                                     if(nodeName === null){
                                         this.root = this.createNewObject(value, null);
                                     }

                                     if(value === "gridpanel" || value === "treepanel"){
                                             isSpecial = true;
                                             special = value;
                                     }else{
                                             child = this.createNewObject(value, null);
                                     }
                                }  
                      }else {
                          isLeaf = false;
                      }
                    }

                    if(isSpecial){
                        child = this.createNewObject(special, properties);
                    }

                    //To add the subnode and its properties to its parent object.
                    if (nodeName !== null && typeof(nodeName) === "string") {
                       if(child === null){
                           Ext.apply(parent, properties);

                       }else{
                           Ext.apply(parent, child);
                       }
                    }

                    if(isLeaf){
                        return;
                    }
                    for (var key in jsonData) {
                        var value = jsonData[key];
                        if (key.toString().indexOf("@") === 0) {
                            continue;
                        }else{
                           if(value === "[object Object]"){
                               for(var index in value){
                                   this.recursiveParser(key, value[index]);                                
                               }
                           }else{                                   
                               this.recursiveParser(key, value);
                           }
                           Ext.apply(this.root, parent);
                        }
                    }
}
```

createNewObject function:

```
createNewObject: function(objType, properties){
    if(objType){
                    switch (objType){
                        case "gridpanel":
                            return new MyProg.base.GridPanel(properties);
                            break;

                        case "treepanel":
                            return new MyProg.base.TreePanel(properties);
                            break;

                        case "tabpanel":
                            return new MyProg.base.TabPanel();

                            break;

                        case "tab":
                            return new MyProg.base.Tabs();
                            break;

                        case "formpanel":
                            return new MyProg.base.Accordion(); 
                            break;

                        case "fieldset":
                            return new MyProg.base.FieldSet(); 
                            break;

                        case "textfield":
                            return new MyProg.base.Fields(); 
                            break;

                        case "panel":
                            return new MyProg.base.Accordion(); 
                            break;

                        default:
                            return new MyProg.base.Accordion(); 

                    };
    };
}
```

data.json:

```
var data = {
            "json": {
                        "@title": "BusinessIntelligence",
                        "@xtype": "tab",
                        "@layout": "accordion",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "@title": "SalesReport",
                                "@ctitle": "SalesReport",
                                "@layout": "column",
                                "items": [
                                    {}
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "@title": "ContentPlayingReport",
                                "@ctitle": "ContentPlayingReport",
                                "@layout": "column",
                                "items": [
                                    {}
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "@title": "BusinessIntelligence",
                                "@ctitle": "BusinessIntelligence",
                                "@layout": "column",
                                "items": [
                                    {}
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
}
```

Comment: I've modified the recursive function. Still the same problem.

Comment: There's not enough information to reproduce the issue: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/mh0

Comment: @TaoWang like Evan said, this is not enough information to reproduce the issue.  The fiddle is parsing the information and creating the object just fine. Please fork the fiddle and make some changes so we can see the issue you are having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the recursion part, it looks more elegant now. All the xtype works just fine, except gridpanel, I've check DOM, everything is in there, but still got error message:

```
TypeError: c is undefined
...+g.extraBaseCls);delete g.autoScroll;if(!g.hasView){if(c.buffered&&!c.remoteSort...  
ext-all.js (line 21, col 1184416)
```

I suspect it's an ExtJS bug. I'll try to find another way out.

recursion program:

```
recursiveParser: function (jsonData) {
    var me = this;
    var properties = {};

    for ( var key in jsonData ){
        var value = jsonData[key];
        var items = (value.constructor === Array) ? [] : {};
        if (value instanceof Object) {
            if (isNaN(key)){
                if (items.constructor === Array) {
                    for (var node in value){
                        items.push(me.recursiveParser(value[node]));
                    }
                    properties[key] = items;

                } else {
                    properties[key] = me.recursiveParser(value);
                }
            } else {
                return me.recursiveParser(value);
            }
        } else {
                if (key.toString().indexOf('@') === 0){
                    key = key.replace('@', '');
                    properties[key] = value;
                }                    
        }
    }
    return properties;
}
```

Comment: Actually, it's not a bug. It's because of the parameter named store in the Grid of JSON-like file. I added double quotes to myContentStore, "@store": "myContentStore", it actually works like this way: "@store": myContentStore.